# Error Deploying Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, deployment, silent-install

I am trying to deploy Google Chrome. I have the GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi I this is the command I used

```
msiexec /i /qn /norestart GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi /l*v chrome.log
```

I get 1722 error, here is the relevant part from the log file

> MSI (s) (0C:74) [10:14:46:340]:
>   Executing op:
>   CustomActionSchedule(Action=DoInstall,ActionType=3074,Source=BinaryData,Target=/silent /install
>   "appguid={8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}&appname=Google
>   Chrome&needsAdmin=True&brand=GGRV"
>   /installsource enterprisemsi /appargs
>   "appguid={8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}&installerdata=%7B%22distribution%22%3A%7B%22msi%22%3Atrue%2C%22system_level%22%3Atrue%2C%22verbose_logging%22%3Atrue%7D%7D",)
>
> MSI (s) (0C:74) [10:20:00:059]: Note:
>   1: 1722 2: DoInstall 3:
>   C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSIF.tmp 4:
>   /silent /install
>   "appguid={8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}&appname=Google
>   Chrome&needsAdmin=True&brand=GGRV"
>   /installsource enterprisemsi /appargs
>   "appguid={8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}&installerdata=%7B%22distribution%22%3A%7B%22msi%22%3Atrue%2C%22system_level%22%3Atrue%2C%22verbose_logging%22%3Atrue%7D%7D"
>
> MSI (s) (0C:74) [10:20:00:059]:
>   Product: Google Chrome -- Error 1722.
>   There is a problem with this Windows
>   Installer package. A program run as
>   part of the setup did not finish as
>   expected. Contact your support
>   personnel or package vendor.  Action
>   DoInstall, location:
>   C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSIF.tmp,
>   command: /silent /install
>   "appguid={8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}&appname=Google
>   Chrome&needsAdmin=True&brand=GGRV"
>   /installsource enterprisemsi /appargs
>   "appguid={8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}&installerdata=%7B%22distribution%22%3A%7B%22msi%22%3Atrue%2C%22system_level%22%3Atrue%2C%22verbose_logging%22%3Atrue%7D%7D"

I have obviously googled this problem, it has been mentioned but no real solution given.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you may want to try this instead:

```
msiexec.exe /qb- /l*vx %LogPath%\chrome.log REBOOT=ReallySuppress UILevel=67 ALLUSERS=2 /i GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi
```

I use this exact syntax when I deploy msi files in MDT 2012, works every time.

- [Reboot=ReallySuppress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reboot) - Best way to make sure 110% that you're suppressing those reboots.
- [UILevel=67](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installer-uilevel) - Hides the install wizard, makes the install "automagical"
- [AllUsers=2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/allusers) - Makes sure the shortcuts icons get put in the user's profile correctly.

I suspect you're missing the logpath variable? by default, its in windows/temp I believe, but double check.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the "GoogleUpdate.exe" from Task Manager before installing the  application